# Data binding not working in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

Im trying to dynamically change the color of a Rectangle but when i try to change it nothing happens

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Name="rootgrid" Margin="0,10,0,-10">

        <Rectangle Name="box3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="56,500,71,182">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color1}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

the first two Rectangles work but box3 doesn't display the color

```
public Program()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyColors color = new MyColors();
    color.color1 = Colors.Yellow;
    box3.DataContext = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);;
}


private SolidColorBrush _color1;

    // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
    public SolidColorBrush color1
    {
        get { return _color1; }
        set
        {
            _color1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("color1");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

the above doesnt throw any errors but it dosent change the fill value of box3, im not sure what im doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

updated the code to reflect changes

Update: Solved
The problem is with visual studio not updating properly the code works in 7.1 but not 8.0

Comment: you need to remove the xaml decleration of DataContext `DataContext="box3"` this will override the one you set in code `box3.DataContext = color;`

Comment: I got rid of DataContext in the xaml and changed Color to SolidColorBrush but its still not showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is Margin of the Rectangle. Change Fill to some static Color in xaml. And see if you can see it. I have tested it and it is not shown. So, I have changed it. And in my opinion you must set Fill to **SolidColorBrush**, not Color. Also delete DataContext from .xaml.

**First Solution:**

And ViewModel:

```
 public class MyColors : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private SolidColorBrush _color1;

        // Declare the PropertyChanged event.
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the property that will be the source of the binding.
        public SolidColorBrush color1
        {
            get { return _color1; }
            set
            {
                _color1 =value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("color1");
            }
        }

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

And MainPage constructor:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    MyColors color = new MyColors();
    color.color1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    box3.DataContext = color;
```

**Second Solution (better):**

But if you want still to use Color then, you can just change it through xaml like that:

```
<Rectangle Name="box3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="56,500,71,182">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color1, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>">
```

Comment: I tried that but im still not seeing anything, i feel like this should be easy and straight forward. does the mode even matter for what im trying to do?

Comment: @user2643346 Have you chnaged margin as I wrote?

Comment: @user2643346 Could you please check my update qith question and anser me.

Comment: Yes i see the blue rectangle, the problem must lie in how im doing data binding but ive looked at examples and it seems right

Comment: @user2643346 Create a new project and check again as I said. May be you have written something somewhere :) Because, it must be worked.

Comment: ive tried it again in a different project and tried to make it simpler by removing the MyColor class and just setting a value but still nothing,

Comment: @user2643346 Ok then. Could you please upload your project to somewhere, for example to skydrive or dropbox.

Comment: i uploaded it to dropbox what name should i use for the invite

Comment: @user2643346 cebiyevferhad@hotmail.com

Comment: @user2643346 You have set DataContext to `box3.DataContext = color.color1;`. 
Change it to `box3.DataContext = color;`

Comment: @user2643346 You have chnaged xaml wrong. If you are using 
`<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color1, Mode=OneWay}" />` in your xaml, then you dont need to make color property as SolidColorBrush. So change your rectangle as you wrote  in the question.

Comment: I beginning to question if my visual studio is even working ive done your suggestions and to no avail. can you save what you have working to the drop box folder because this is really driving me up a wall

Comment: @user2643346 :) ok. But, I am wokring on VS2010 and WP7.1.  BUt it is same. Do you have Wp 7.1 installed?

Comment: i dont have it installed but i can install it

Comment: @user2643346 ok. Then I am uploading it to DropBox.  Tell me your e-mail.

Comment: @user2643346 I have sent. I am not using DropBox usually. I dont know how to do it. I just share my app with you.  Also, could you please tell me the result.

Comment: So im still not seeing anything on the version you sent me and you can see the rectangle, so this tells me it must be something with my visual studio 2012...

Comment: @user2643346 May be. You opened my application in WP 8.0  emulator?

Comment: No, i have to deploy to a device to test apps, i have a couple more minutes till 7.1 is installed

Comment: okay it works in the 7.1 emulator so it is a problem with visual studio, thank you farhad for your help, im marking this as answered now

Comment: @user2643346 Glad to help. But, it is very weird why it doesn't work for wp8.0

Answer (score 0):

You have the `DataContext` set twice, once in Xaml and once in code, and `Fill` is a `Brush` not a `Color` you will have to set the Fill's color property

```
<Rectangle Name="box3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="56,500,71,182">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color1}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: I removed it and still nothing.

Comment: Ohh.. I see the issue, `Fill` is a `Brush` not a `Color` you will have to set the Fill's color property, added edit to my answer